# Laravel update column for all users based on old value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `days` column in my users table, I need to run a cron job command using Laravel to decrease 1 from the users `days` column.

I know that I can use it to update all rows at once:

```
DB::table('Users')->update(['column' => 'value']);
```

But how I can set `value` to each member `days - 1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 
`DB::table('Users')->decrement('days', 1);`
Or,
Since you want to decrement by 1, you can skip value part.
`DB::table('Users')->decrement('days');`

Find details here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#increment-and-decrement

Answer (score 0):

You can update by: DB::table('Users')->update(['column' => DB::raw('value + 7')]);
Of course if you don't want to decrement or increment!